# Docker use ip from host

Tags: windows, docker, networking, docker-for-windows

I have the problem, that I want to create multiple docker container (with docker-compose) and call each container with the ip address.
On a Linux host it works but not in Windows as host.

Example:

```
container 1 (php) ip: 192.168.100.10  
container 2 (mysql) ip: 192.168.100.11  
container 3 (nginx) ip: 192.168.100.12
```

so I want to add a hosts item with the ip of the nginx to use a hostname like project.local for develop on browser.

Have anyone a idea what I must do on windows to realize this?

Answer (score 1):

Each container use a internal IP for the base system that you using with your containers, for example if you are using Linux all container will have an internal IP that can be seen between container, but not for the principal host, if you want to connect to the containers you will need to use the ports for example for MySQL 3306, if the containers aren't seen between it you will need to create links or networks using a docker compose or the bash to set up this configuration, here I adjunct an example:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks

```
version: "3"
services:

  proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    networks:
      - frontend
  app:
    build: ./app
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  frontend:
    # Use a custom driver
    driver: custom-driver-1
  backend:
    # Use a custom driver which takes special options
    driver: custom-driver-2
    driver_opts:
      foo: "1"
      bar: "2"
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links

```
version: "3"
services:

  web:
    build: .
    links:
      - "db:database"
  db:
    image: postgres
```

Comment: The logic of the internal docker network i understand and to use the ports is more a temporarily solution... a lot of tutorial try to explane to use the connect to the docker network from windows host but each of this are only show with one docker container and not with docker compose. So it woun't work :'( 
With Linux-Host it will be connect (even automaticly) so i think it there is any why for windows too.